# retrofit callback keep the same paramerters

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

im using RetroFit (2.3.0) in order to get JSON data.
in this code i'm trying to call a retrofit Async callback in order to iterate over a list and get json data back for each of the objects in the array im iterating (uncheckedBets).

In the logs i can see the 'i' variable is progressing great, going from 0 to 3, just as i need (there are 4 objects in the array) but the retrofit call always makes the same call first object from the array.

so i get this log:

```
i= 0 ------> 2223233
Game in getGameStatus: Game{gameId=2223233, compId=1261, gameDate='25.12.2017', season='2017/2018', week='15', gameVenueName='Yaakov Turner Toto Stadium (Be’ér Shéva (Beer Sheva) )', gameVenueId='86831', gameVenueCity='Beer 
i= 1 ------> 2223414
Game in getGameStatus: Game{gameId=2223233, compId=1261, gameDate='25.12.2017', season='2017/2018', week='15', gameVenueName='Yaakov Turner Toto Stadium (Be’ér Shéva (Beer Sheva) )', gameVenueId='86831', gameVenueCity='Be
i= 2 ------> 2223417
Game in getGameStatus: Game{gameId=2223233, compId=1261, gameDate='25.12.2017', season='2017/2018', week='15', gameVenueName='Yaakov Turner Toto Stadium (Be’ér Shéva (Beer Sheva) )', gameVenueId='86831', gameVenueCity='Beer Sh
i= 3 ------> 2223418
Game in getGameStatus: Game{gameId=2223233, compId=1261, gameDate='25.12.2017', season='2017/2018', week='15', gameVenueName='Yaakov Turner Toto Stadium (Be’ér Shéva (Beer Sheva) )', gameVenueId='86
```

the code:

```
 private void getGameStatus() {
    i = 0;
    callMatchScoreChecker();
}

private void callMatchScoreChecker() {
if(i>=uncheckedBets.size()){
    return;
}
    Log.e("###","i= "+i+" ------> "+uncheckedBets.get(i).getMatchID());
    GetGamesDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetGamesDataService.class);
    Call<ArrayList<Game>> call = service.getMatchData(uncheckedBets.get(i).getMatchID(), TodayGames.AUTH_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Game>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Game>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<Game>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Game newGame = response.body().get(0);
                if (newGame.getStatus().equals("FT") || newGame.getStatus().equals("Pen.")) {
                    //Game is over, check the bet
                    Log.e("###","Game in getGameStatus: "+newGame.toString());
                    i++;
                    callMatchScoreChecker();
                    /*
                    boolean isBetSuccessful = checkIfBetWasCorrect(matchBet, newGame.getHomeScore(), newGame.getVisitorScore());
                    OldBet currentBet = new OldBet(matchBet, matchID, newGame.getCompId(), newGame.getHomeTeamId(), newGame.getVisitorTeamId(), newGame.getStartTime(), true, isBetSuccessful);
                    Log.e("###", newGame.getGameId() + ", The BET: " + matchID + ", The Result Of Bet:" + currentBet.isWellPlacedBet());
                    */
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Game>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Because it's Async request, so it does not know when to return, what to return inside a for loop. You need to use Sync request , or put request in seprerated thread (i'm not sure about 2nd idea)

Comment: ok i changed it to sync request and it's working. now im just afraid it will make too long requests on the main thread. isn't a service supposed to be a async task by default?

Comment: You can try using RxJava (ReactiveX Java) for helping on Synch request. Depend on API design and how do you want to use the return data, you still can use Async, for sure

Comment: so i can just wrap the whole service functions inside a AsyncTask and that's it?